# Labeling one to many relationship class using ArcMap

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-10.1, labeling, relationship-class

I’ve created a feature class with a one to many relationships to a table.

One point many classes.

However I want to label the point with the classes attributes.

Esri wrote VB [solution](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/CPP_VB6_VBA_VCPP_Doc/COM_Samples_Docs/Cartography/Labeling_and_Annotation/OneToManyLabels/d5daadc3-3514-4572-b8e9-8f2c7aeede07.htm) but it's not supported at version 10.1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

i found the answer [here](http://wolfmapper.wordpress.com/2012/08/28/displaying-a-multi-row-table-label-in-arcgis-using-python/) at wolf mapper blog -
 right click on the point shapefile and select “Properties” > “Labels” tab > “Expression…” button. In the “Label Expression” window select “Python” as the “Parser:” and click the check-box next to “Advanced.” Insert the following code:

```
    def FindLabel ( [LocID] ):

   import arcpy
   myDataTable = "data table" #insert data table name
   myComponent = "Arsenic" #insert component name
   myScreeningLevel = "32" #insert exceedance  level
   myQuerySelect = '"location_id"' + " = '" + [LocID] + "' and " + '"component"' + " like '" + myComponent + "%'"
   myFieldsQuerySelect = "OBJECTID; location_id; component; top_depth_inches; bottom_depth_inches; result; units"
   mySortQuerySelect = "top_depth_inches"
   myText = ""

   mxd = mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")

   for table in arcpy.mapping.ListTableViews(mxd):
     if table.name == myDataTable:
       rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(table, myQuerySelect, "", myFieldsQuerySelect, mySortQuerySelect)
       myText = "<BOL>" + [LocID] + "</BOL>\n" + "<ITA>" + myComponent + "</ITA>" + "\n"
       currentState = ""
       for row in rows:
         if currentState != row.OBJECTID:
           currentState = row.OBJECTID
         if float(row.result) >= float(myScreeningLevel):
           myText = myText + str(int(row.top_depth_inches)) + '&quot;-' + str(int(row.bottom_depth_inches)) + "&quot; <BOL><CLR red = '255'>" + str(row.result) + "</CLR></BOL> " + str(row.units) + "\n"
         else:
           myText = myText + str(int(row.top_depth_inches)) + '&quot;-' + str(int(row.bottom_depth_inches)) + '&quot; ' + str(row.result) + " " + str(row.units) + "\n"

       return myText
```