# How to build query expression to display text from one-to-many relationship in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, enterprise-geodatabase, spatial-database, query, relates

I have two tables in an enterprise geodatabase stored in PostgreSQL and accessed via ArcSDE:

parcel and person
 1 or + parcel can have 1 or + person (relationship is pll_person)
[image]

I can display all  parcels with annotation "id"

What I want is to display in each parcel the Name of the person(s) in the related table - see picture please :

[image]

**I want to display parcels proprietor name  as annotation please any suggestion ?**

Comment: What do you want to happen when multiple persons are associated with a parcel?

Comment: Also, is your data stored in a file geodatabase, personal geodatabase, or enterprise geodatabase?

Comment: I want to show on the parcel all the owners "it's a relational  annotation "

Comment: possible duplicate of [Label one to many relationship class](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/50106/label-one-to-many-relationship-class). The comment of @Georg shows a solution.

Comment: database  stored in potgresQL i use arcSDE

Comment: I think it would be much more efficient to use a [query layer](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/What_is_a_query_layer/00s50000000n000000/) than the label expression solution proposed in the linked question. I don't have an example handy though.

Comment: You could also create a [spatial view](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/help/arcgis_server_dotnet_help/index.html#//002p000000sr000000) if you want to persist its definition in the DB.

Comment: @blah238 I don't work with query layers but am curious how they are used to put out the stacked text evident in the graphic.  Consequently, I think the "[**wolfmapper"**](http://wolfmapper.wordpress.com/2012/08/28/displaying-a-multi-row-table-label-in-arcgis-using-python/) solution would be my preference.

Comment: I don't think it is annotation (in the ArcGIS sense) being sought here - it looks like labelling using stacked text derived from a one-to-many relationship.

Comment: @PolyGeo this could be done as part of the query: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8803563/386205

Comment: Just use a newline (`\n`) instead of a comma. If for some reason that doesn't work, another delimiter could be used, and then a (much simpler) label expression could be used to split it back out to multiple lines.

Answer (score 3):

I have only done this kind of thing with SQL Server but this link has some techniques that should help you accomplish what you want with PostGres.

[How to concatenate strings field in postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43870/how-to-concatenate-strings-of-a-string-field-in-a-postgresql-group-by-query/2292862#2292862)

The steps you would need to carry out would be:

1. Create a View in the database (using the techniques described in the link) that returns a table with two fields, 
   Parcel Id and Concatenated Owners Names.  Note that the delimiter
   between names will need to be a carriage return as opposed to a
   comma.
2. Open the View in ArcGIS; one way to do this would be as a query layer.
3. Join the View to the Parcels using the Parcel ID