# How to display variable number of images associated with one point on QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have a set of point locations. I have a set of images with reference numbers. I'd like a way to easily see the images associated with the location, using QGIS.

This is for my own use rather than necessarily for communicating to others, so it should stay on QGIS if possible and the solution should be 'live' (or at least should be very easily updated) rather than involving a one-off import/export of any kind.

At the moment these are vector images, but could easily be raster. On this occasion it's images of sign designs, but in the future might be something else - perhaps photos.

A key issue is that one location has anything from 0 - 5 images associated with it. I'm expecting to produce a text file associating locations with image references (i.e. with two columns, location reference and image reference). It's not beyond the bounds of possibility that I could something more imaginative (database etc). I'm beginning to explore the capacity of QGIS to work with one-to-many relationships. It looks like for ArcGIS the answer might lie with [python code based labelling](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/50106/labeling-one-to-many-relationship-class-using-arcgis-for-desktop) - is there an equivalent?

The issue is that I don't really have a clue what the options might be so can't investigate them, nor even how to ask this question in a really clear and directed way... but I'm sure that others have the same question.

Answer (score 1):

This won't answer your question but hopefully might shed some light and give you some ideas. You could use **SVG annotations** to *manually* place points on a mark and include images (.svg format):

[image: SVG Annotation option]

[image: SVG Annotation]

When you insert an annotation, double-click on it to open up its options and you can select the path to the file along with other editing options for borders, colours etc.

Hope this is of some use!

Comment: Interesting - thanks - do I understand correctly that the annotations are not connected to any data, but are a decorative layer saved as part of the QGIS project? I note that like with the call out things (map tips?) HTML can be used. I was wondering if some fancy HTML coding would do what I want, but my instinct is that we're probably talking about something which is beyond HTML

Comment: You're right about annotations being a decorative layer and only saved in a project. I can't tell you about HTML as I haven't used it as an annotation, apologies! I would like to think that it is possible to make HTML annotations as fancy and complex but hopefully others can advise on this issue.